# Global variables in R

Tags: r, global-variables, variable-assignment

I am poking into the manuals, I wanted to ask the community:
How can we set global variables inside a function?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

As Christian's answer with `assign()` shows, there is a way to assign in the global environment.  A simpler, shorter (but not better ... stick with assign) way is to use the `<<-` operator, ie

```
    a <<- "new"
```

inside the function.

Comment: This approach actually does not save in global environment, but instead in the parent scope. Sometimes parent scope will be the same as the global environment, though in some cases with lots of nested functions it won't.

Comment: Why is `assign` preferred to `<<-`?

Comment: @Jasha `<<-` will search up the chain of enclosures up to the global environment and assign to the first matching variable it finds. Hypothetically, if you have a function `f()` nested in a closure `g()` and `a` exists in `g()`, then using `a <<-` in `f()` will assign to `a` in `g()`, not to the global environment. Oftentimes, this is what you want, however.

Answer (score 126):

I found a solution for how to set a global variable in a [mailinglist posting](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/11/16539.html) via [assign](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html):

```
a <- "old"
test <- function () {
   assign("a", "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
test()
a  # display the new value
```

Comment: see also the accepted answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969852/update-data-frame-via-function-doesnt-work for updating dataframes within a function

Comment: What if the function is within `mclapply`?

Answer (score 18):

What about `.GlobalEnv$a <- "new"` ? I saw this explicit way of creating a variable in a certain environment here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html. It seems shorter than using the `assign()` function.