# Using "global" variables in function given to apply. We could see them, but could not assign values

Tags: r, scope, apply, operation

Consider the following R-code:

```
i <- 10
j <- 0
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
apply(m, 1, function(x) {
 if(i > 0)
  j<-1 
  else 
   j<-2 
 return <- i
})
```

Inside the function we can read the content of the variable i, but we cannot manipulate the content of the variable j? But when we can read variables inside the function I would expect that we can assign new values to them too? So can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: It's generally bad form in R to implicitly alter the values of global variables from within a function. The preferred method is to do this explicitly by assigning the new value of the output of the function. Within the function, you are altering a copy of i rather than i itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update data frame via function doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969852/update-data-frame-via-function-doesnt-work)

Comment: To assign in global environment you can use `<<-` or `assign`

Comment: @NBATrends You *can*, but it's almost never a good idea "[because global variables introduce non-obvious dependencies between functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)"

Comment: @phil I agree here, never implied it was a good idea. Just showing how it can be done