# Trouble to assign value to a data frame with my.function - With R -

Tags: r, function, dataframe, variable-assignment

I have a problem to assign a value with my function.

x1 is a data.frame

```
n_grams<- function(x1) {
a<- x1[which(x1[,3]=="relato"),2]
b<- x1[which(x1[,3]=="tiembla"),2]
c<- x1[which(x1[,3]=="kristina"),2]
if(c== a+2)  {
x1[c,5]<- -1
}
}
```

What i´m doing is looking for a combination of three words in my data frame x1. If the words are one after the other ones, the word "kristina" will have the value -1. The number 2 is the column wich indicates the number of position of the word; number five is the score of the word in my data.frame.

For some reason, this code doesn´t work, but if I apply it withougt a function, it makes the assigment perfectly.

The code runs until  `x1[c,5]<- -1`. I checked.

I tried `ifelse()` and the retun vakue was FALSE.

Finnaly, i need a functiion because a have many combinations of words, so it would be more tidy if a create a function instead of spread elements all over my enviroment.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: can you share a sample of your data and the expected output.. nice that you shared your code(what you tried) but for our better understanding we need a sample data

Comment: I'm sorry but stackoverflow doesn´t let me upload a picture in this answer to you. I uploaded moments ago with an answer to this post but I think it has been deleted. What wolud you like to know about my data.frame?

Comment: assume your data is called `df`. So execute `dput(df)` in your console and share those results here. Also add the expected output that you desire form the df .

Comment: Hi everybody: Finnaly, I could solution my problem. Here is the answer.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969852/update-data-frame-via-function-doesnt-work