# Return a changed list in R via lapply(), but objects in list not changed

Tags: r, list, global-variables, lapply

I'm trying to loop through a list of data frames, dropping columns that don't match some condition. I want to change the data frames such that they're missing 1 column essentially. After executing the function, I'm able to change the LIST of data frames, but not the original data frames themselves.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
                  a = c("John","Peter","Dylan"),
                  b = c(1, 2, 3),
                  c = c("yipee", "ki", "yay"))

df2 <- data.frame(
  a = c("Ray","Bob","Derek"),
  b = c(4, 5, 6),
  c = c("yum", "yummy", "donuts"))


df3 <- data.frame(
  a = c("Bill","Sam","Nate"),
  b = c(7, 8, 9),
  c = c("I", "eat", "cake"))

l <- list(df1, df2, df3)

drop_col <- function(x) {
  x <- x[, !names(x) %in% c("e", "b", "f")]
  return(x)
}

l <- lapply(l, drop_col)
```

When I call the list l, I get a list of data frames with the changes I want. When I call an element in the list, df1 or df2 or df3, they do not have a dropped column.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969852/update-data-frame-via-function-doesnt-work) solution and many others, I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: I don't understand. You are iterating over the list and changing the list, not the data frames. So why would you think that your code would change the data frames df1 to df3?

Comment: Yes, my question is, how do I actually change the data frames themselves? I'm just using the list to loop through them...

Comment: The objects in the list are changed, which is not consistent with the title of your question. The original data frames are not changed because your drop_col function is working on your list, l. Maybe just extract out the data frames within your updated list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`l` list and `df1` , `df2` etc. dataframes are independent. They have nothing to do with each other. One way to get new changed dataframes is to assign names to the list and create new dataframe.

```
l <- lapply(l, drop_col)
names(l) <- paste0("df", 1:3)
list2env(l, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I don't want a new single dataframe, I want to keep the three separate. Also calling l just gives me the same thing as what I have before, a list of dataframes. How do I change the original dataframes?

Comment: @potato It doesn't give a single dataframe, they are all different. You need to 1) run the `drop_col` function on list.  2) Name them 3) Use `list2env` 4) Check `df1`, `df2` etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you are creating `l`, you are filling it with copies of your data frames `df1`, `df2`, `df3`.
In R, it is not generally possible to pass references to variables. One workaround is to create an environment as @Ronak Shah does.

Another is to use `get()` and `<<-` to change the variable within the function.

```
drop_cols <- function(x) {
  for(iter in x)
    do.call("<<-", list(iter, drop_col(get(iter))))
}
drop_cols(c("df1","df2","df3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  a = c("John","Peter","Dylan"),
  b = c(1, 2, 3),
  c = c("yipee", "ki", "yay"))

df2 <- data.frame(
  a = c("Ray","Bob","Derek"),
  b = c(4, 5, 6),
  c = c("yum", "yummy", "donuts"))


df3 <- data.frame(
  a = c("Bill","Sam","Nate"),
  b = c(7, 8, 9),
  c = c("I", "eat", "cake"))
# Name the list elements:
l <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)

drop_col <- function(x) {
  x <- x[, !names(x) %in% c("e", "b", "f")]
  return(x)
}

l <- lapply(l, drop_col)

# View altered dfs:
View(l["df1"])
```