# Concatenate values of the structure inside of a function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops

I want to run a  function called autocorrelation over several data frames. Also, I want to save the values of the structure called Ac_results I get every time I run the function. Therefore, it is like I want to concatenate the values one below another every time the function runs. Currently, I create a data frame outside the function and try to update it inside the function concatenating the new values using the function `cbind`, but it is not working. Any idea about how to solve it?

```
Ac <- data.frame("Name"=character(),"Lag1"=double(),"Low"=double(),"Up"=double(),"Significance"=character())

#AUTOCORRELATION
autocorrelation <- function(x,y,i){
  mean_x <- mean(x)
  Denominador <- (x[] - mean(x))^2 #Denominator 
  k=1; n=length(x)-k; u=1
  Numerador <- numeric(n)
  for (u in 1:n) {
    Numerador[u] <- (x[u] - mean_x)*(x[u+k] - mean_x) #Numerador
  }
  Lag1 <- ifelse(sum(Denominador)!=0,((1/(length(x)-1))*sum(Numerador))/((1/length(x))*sum(Denominador)),0) #Lag 1
  low <- (-1 - (1.96*sqrt(length(x)-2)))/(length(x)-1) #5% significance level
  up <- (-1 + (1.96*sqrt(length(x)-2)))/(length(x)-1) #5% significance level
  Significance <- ifelse( up <= Lag1 & Lag1 >= low,"Independent","No independent") #Significance
  Ac_results <- structure(list(Name=y,Lag1=Lag1,Low=low,Up=up,Significance=Significance)) #save the results
  Ac <- cbind(Ac, Ac_results)
}

write.csv(Ac, file ="Lag.csv")
```

Comment: Functions should not modify variables outside their scope. The function should return an updated value that you can save later.

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample about how to do that?

Comment: This existing question pretty much sums it up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969852/update-data-frame-via-function-doesnt-work