# code executes outside function, but not inside it

Tags: r, function, relational, quotation-marks

my problem is, that some **code gets executed outside a function, but not in it**. In my example, the content of certain cells should be transferred from the input table to the output table. In case of removal or adding of rows/cols I don't access the cells by their index (e.g input[3,4]), but by application of a condition (e.g. input[(which(input$code=="A1")),(which(colnames(input)=="kg"))].

so here's a minimized version of my data:

```
input<-data.frame(animal=c("cat","dog","mouse","deer","lion"),
                  m=c(0.5,1,0.1,1.5,3),
                  kg=c(5,20,0.2,50,100),
                  code=c("A4","A5","A3","A1","A2"))
output<-data.frame(code=c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"),
                  kg=numeric(5))
```

execution outside the function, that works (the content of a cell of the input table should be copied to a suitable one in the output table):

```
row_out<-which(output$code=="A1")
col_out<-which(colnames(output)=="kg")
row_in<-which(input$code=="A1")
col_in<-which(colnames(input)=="kg")

output[row_out,col_out]<-input[row_in,col_in]
```

and the function, that contains the same code, which worked outside, except for the substitution of the quoted code expression for a function argument (codeexpression):

```
fun_transfer<-function(codeexpression){
  row_out<-which(output$code==codeexpression)
  col_out<-which(colnames(output)=="kg")
  row_in<-which(input$code==codeexpression)
  col_in<-which(colnames(input)=="kg")
  output[row_out,col_out]<-input[row_in,col_in]
}
```

Problem: now the execution of

```
fun_transfer("A4")
```

does not lead to an error, nor to a result in the output table.

Why doesn't this function work or rather what does it do? Is there a problem with quotation marks?
any help would be appreciated
thanks,
Michel

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969852/update-data-frame-via-function-doesnt-work

Comment: I think @RonakShah's link will start you down the right path. A very key sentence in that answer is *"it's good form to pass all necessary objects as arguments to the function"*. I might extend it a little to say *"it's poor form to use objects not explicitly passed to the function"*, for several reasons but mostly centered on reduced reproducibility and difficult in troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks RonakShah and r2evans, your hints might solve my question. First tries seemed to be promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the best case, data enters a function as argument and leaves it as a return value.

Outside of a function

```
output[row_out,col_out] <- input[row_in,col_in]
```

changes the existing data.frame. You can (or better: should) not change some variable outside the function from within the function.

Just end your function with a `return` statement to return the changed dataframe to the caller

**Edit**

It appears as if what you try to write is a lesser version of `merge`. If the following answers your question it will probably be more concise, faster and more idiomatic:

```
input<-data.frame(animal=c("cat","dog","mouse","deer","lion"),
                  m=c(0.5,1,0.1,1.5,3),
                  kg=c(5,20,0.2,50,100),
                  code=c("A4","A5","A3","A1","A2"))
output<-data.frame(code=c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"))


output <- merge(output, input[, c("code", "kg")], by = "code", 
                all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
print(output)
```

Comment: thanks Bernard! the return statement works, and now I have to deal with applying the function several times to copy all cells

Comment: @michel please check whether the inbuild function `merge` suits your needs. If not, please explain more detailed what exactly needs to be done.