# Can I not use Global vars in R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236620/global-variables-in-r)

ad the beginning of the file I wrote:

```
t.code = c()
```

then in a function like:

```
calc <- function(){

   ..some stuff

   t.code = append(t.code, value)
}
```

at the end i print the **t.code** content but I see NULL, so it seems that the global var is not used, any advice?

Comment: The idiomatic way to assign a variable in R is to use `<-` rather than `=`. But you are looking for `<<-` in this case: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html  From the docs: The operators <<- and ->> cause a search to made through the environment for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment.

Comment: Assigning to a global variable is very rarely necessary (or a good idea) especially if you're new to R.  I would instead have your function `return(value)` and append in a separate step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can but you'll have to use the global assignment operator `<<-` (or somewhat more sophisticated, `assign`).

```
t.code <<- append(t.code,value)
```

And now the standard disclaimer: the use of `<<-` is often discouraged, as that style of programming is not really the sort of idiom that R was intended for.

You might benefit from a careful reading of R's [scoping](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope) rules.

Comment: `<<-` only assigns in the global environment if the variable isn't found in any of the searched environments.