# Why does "<<-" messes with the scope of a function in Shiny

Tags: r, scope, shiny

I run into a very interesting problem. I wrote a function and wanted to check the output of some variables within the function as well as the return result.

```
observe({
    result <- myFunction()
})


myFunction <- function() {
    # some calculations
    # ...

    # create Dataframe from previous calculated variables
    # I was interested in the result of problematicVariable
    # thats why I wanted to make it global for checking, after
    # closing down the shiny app

    problematicVariable <<- data.frame(...)


    if(someCondition) {
        # ...        

    } else {
        # some calculations
        # ...
        # now I used problematicVariable for the first time

        foo <- data.frame(problematicVariable$bar, problematicVariable$foo)
    }
```

That gave me

> data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: ...

However, since I made `problematicVariable` global I run the line where the App crashed manually (`foo <- data.frame(problematicVariable$bar, problematicVariable$foo)`). There was absolutely no problem. So I thought, that this is strange... 
I got rid of the double `<<` and changed it to `problematicVariable <- ...` and now it works.
So, using `<<-` to assign `problematicVariable` somehow made `problematicVariable` not available in the `if...else`.

Why causes `<<-` a behaviour like this? That messes with the scope?!

Comment: This is not C, properly define a function and its inputs and outputs. If the problem still occurs, provide a small, reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

`<<-` doesn't always create variables in the global environment. It will, however, create variables in the parent scope. Sometimes the parent scope is the same as the global environment.

`?assign` is what you want. But I don't see any reason to create global variables from inside a function. Just return the variable - code is easier to debug that way and you'll get fewer unexpected results.

EDIT: Suspected that this was a dupe. Good discussion about this can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236620/global-variables-in-r)

Comment: Not exactly dupe since there's a crash (not clearly defined, but still) from a Shiny app.