# R package: using lapply to do.call a list of internal functions

Tags: r, package

I am developing an R package in which I have an exported function that needs to call several unexported functions and store the results from each in a list.
Which functions are called is variable and depends on user input.

My approach to this was to `lapply` a (character) vector of function names with `do.call`, but it seems like this makes the unexported functions invisible to the exported function.

Consider the following example package code:

```r
tmp1 <- function(x) print(paste("Function 1 called with x =", x))
tmp2 <- function(x) print(paste("Function 2 called with x =", x))
tmp3 <- function(x) print(paste("Function 3 called with x =", x))

#' @export
test1 <- function() {
  tmp1("test")
  tmp2("test")
  tmp3("test")
}

#' @export
test2 <- function() {
  funs <- c("tmp1", "tmp2", "tmp3")
  for (fun in funs) do.call(fun, list(x = "test"))
}

#' @export
test3 <- function() {
  funs <- c("tmp1", "tmp2", "tmp3")
  lapply(funs, do.call, list(x = "test"))
}
```

After building and loading the package, running the three `test` functions yield the following output:

```r
test1()
#> [1] "Function 1 called with x = test"
#> [1] "Function 2 called with x = test"
#> [1] "Function 3 called with x = test"

test2()
#> [1] "Function 1 called with x = test"
#> [1] "Function 2 called with x = test"
#> [1] "Function 3 called with x = test"

test3()
#> Error in tmp1(x = "test"): could not find function "tmp1"
```

Calling the functions directly works, and calling them with `do.call` works when using `do.call` directly, but it fails when calling them via `lapply`.
I can make a workaround with the for-loop, but I am curious as to why this happens.

So, my question is twofold:

1. Why are the unexported functions invisible to `do.call` when called inside `lapply`?
2. Can I make the `lapply(funs, do.call, list(...))` approach work?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. When I create a package with your code it works fine for me. But, anyway, I think when you're writing a package you should specify where these functions can be found using `::`.

Comment: Does using `funs <- c(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3)` instead of `funs <- c("tmp1", "tmp2", "tmp3")` solve your issue ? Or do `lapply(mget(funs), do.call, list(x = "test"))` which amounts to the same

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper it makes `test3` run, but it doesn't answer my question (i.e. _why_ the `lapply` approach fails), and besides, in my actual package, `funs` will be a character vector specified (to some extent) by the user.

Comment: Then using `mget` should solve it, though it doesn't answer why it doesn't work. Working with function objects is cleaner IMHO.

Comment: `do.call` evaluates by default its character arguments in `parent.frame()`, when using `lapply` you're doing some environment gymnastics that makes your code fail (unfortunately I don't know enough to say much more), so you can probably also solve your issue by tweaking the `envir` parameter. From `?do.call` : `envir 
an environment within which to evaluate the call. This will be most useful if what is a character string and the arguments are symbols or quoted expressions.`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper After playing around with the `envir` parameter, 
I found that: `lapply(funs, do.call, args = list(x = "test"), envir = environment())` runs correctly -- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments on the question, I have a (partial) answer:

1. `do.call` by default evaluates character arguments in `parent.frame()`, and when called inside `lapply`, this is a different environment  than the one the `tmp` functions are defined in (though I'm not sure about the specifics)
2. Supplying the current environment to `do.call` makes the `lapply` approach work:
   `lapply(funs, do.call, args = list(x = "test"), envir = environment())`

Answer (score 0):

This has partly been covered elsewhere, I recommend you to read these two([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628621/how-do-you-use-scoping-assignment-in-r), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236620/global-variables-in-r)) threads here at stackoverflow on global variables and scoping assignment.

To solve your problem, add "`<<-`" when assigning your functions, i.e.

```
tmp1 <<- function(x) print(paste("Function 1 called with x =", x))
tmp2 <<- function(x) print(paste("Function 2 called with x =", x))
tmp3 <<- function(x) print(paste("Function 3 called with x =", x))
```

**Output:**

```
> test1()
[1] "Function 1 called with x = test"
[1] "Function 2 called with x = test"
[1] "Function 3 called with x = test"
> 
> test2()
[1] "Function 1 called with x = test"
[1] "Function 2 called with x = test"
[1] "Function 3 called with x = test"
> test3()
[1] "Function 1 called with x = test"
[1] "Function 2 called with x = test"
[1] "Function 3 called with x = test"
[[1]]
[1] "Function 1 called with x = test"

[[2]]
[1] "Function 2 called with x = test"

[[3]]
[1] "Function 3 called with x = test"
```

Comment: Doing this caused `devtools::document` to place definitions for the `tmp` functions in the global environment, which is definitely not what I want, and loading the package from a fresh session, `test3` still doesn't work (in fact, none of the `test` functions work)