# R Global-Variable Reference/Definition from Within a Function

Tags: r, function, variables, global, definition

In

[Global variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236620/global-variables-in-r)

we have code

```
a <- "old"
test <- function () {
   assign("a", "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
test()
a  # display the new value
```

If we remove the 'a <- "old"' command, and run with a clear workspace, we see that test() not only modifies the value of variable "a", test() also DEFINES "a" for the program.

Comment: Assigning to `.GlobalEnv` is often discouraged. Use lists instead? What is the expected behavior though?

Comment: What is the question?