# Using global variables as input to R function

Tags: r, matlab, function, package, global-variables

There are plenty of examples about updating global variables from the inside of R functions by using `<<-` or `assign()` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1236620/1169233) is just one example), but I can't find any examples on how to use such variables as input for functions. For instance, consider this MATLAB function, which is just a complicated way of adding pi to a number:

```matlab
function final = parentFun(why)
    global pie
    pie = pi;
    final = childFun(why);
end

function y = childFun(x)
    global pie
    y = x + pie;
end
```

So that

```
>> parentFun(100)

ans =

  103.1416
```

**I would like to recreate this in R**. The closest I got was by nesting `childFun` into `parentFun` like this:

```r
parentFun <- function(why) {
    pie <- pi
    childFun <- function(x) {
        x + pie
    }
    childFun(why)
}
```

And indeed

```
> parentFun(100)
[1] 103.1416
```

The problem is that in my real case `parentFun` is a couple hundred lines long and it contains several children which can be just as long. In other words, **nesting is basically off the table**.

Also, these are functions in a package, so `pie` is in fact acquired from within a function and isn't started by a script.

Of course, separating both functions doesn't work because `childFun()` can't see `pie`:

```
> parentFun <- function(why) {
        pie <- pi
        childFun(why)
}
> childFun <- function(x) {
        x + pie
}
> parentFun(100)
Error in x + pie : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to change the environment of `childfun`

```
childFun <- function(x) {
        x + pie
}

parentFun <- function(why) {
        pie <- pi
        environment(childFun) <- environment()
        childFun(why)
}

parentFun(100)
[1] 103.1416
```

This has to do with lexical scoping of R. When you call a function R looks for the variables inside the function environment first. If it is not sucessful R continues the search in parent environments (in your case the global environment).

By writing `environment(childFun) <- environment()` you tell the function to look in the environment of `parentFun` for variables.

I recommend [this book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) if you want to learn more about environments.

Comment: Interesting! This remind me I have so much to learn about actively handling environments. I'll see where this takes me. Thank you for the answer and the book recommendation!